# django cannot delete audio file because it is used by audio player

Tags: python, django, audio

I have created a django website in which users can upload music files and play them using the HTML5 audio player

Those are my models

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.


class User(models.Model):


    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True,null=False,blank=False)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True,null=False,blank=False)
    name=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=40,null=False,blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.title()+","+self.email


class Song(models.Model):

    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)
    artist=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,null=False,blank=False)
    file = models.FileField(null=False,blank=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist+" - "+self.title


# I can't delete the song file because it's used by the audio player in html
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Song)
def submission_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.file.delete(False)
```

This the html code for displaying songs

```
{% for song in songs %}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{song.artist}} - {{song.title}}</h5>
            <audio controls>
                <source src="/media/{{song.file}}" type="audio/ogg" />
            </audio>
        <a href="/delete/{{song.id}}" onclick="confirm_delete_song('/delete/{{song.id}}')" class="delete" > <i class="material-icons" title="Supprimer">&#xE872;</i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And the view that deletes the song

```
def delete(request, song):
    if 'logged' not in request.session:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        try:
            Song.objects.get(id=song).delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        except:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

A screenshot of the page

[image]

When I click on the delete button, the song is removed from the database but the file is not deleted even if I haven't played the audio yet

After some debugging, it seems that the audio player is using the audio file which is why django cannot delete it

**[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\Amine\Desktop\omp\media\remix.mp3'**

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does `Song.objects.get(id=song).delete()` delete the file?

Comment: the receiver in my model was working but when i added the audio tag the file is no longer deleted

Comment: maybe it's hitting an exception (is the server on windows) try adding some logging...

Comment: This is what I got : [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\Amine\\Desktop\\omp\\media\\remix.mp3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix the issue by using javascript to set the src attribute of the audio tag to an empty string just before deleting. This caused the file to be free

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
def delete(request, song):
    if 'logged' not in request.session:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        try:
            song = Song.objects.get(id=song)
            song.file.delete()  # File delete
            song.delete # object delete
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        except:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: thanks but still not working the audio player is using the file so i can't delete it

Comment: Is someone accessing it while deletion?

Comment: yes the audio tag was using it but now it's working after I set the src attr to empty